# Kaplan Meier Retirement Analysis

Tags: r, survival, kaplan-meier

**Scenario:**

I am trying to find the probability someone retires at a specific age using the survival probability package in R. The way I am trying to frame this study is by only looking at individuals who are 57 years or older within the time window of 2000 to 2018. So that means anyone who turn 57 within 2000-2018 is initiated into the study and tracked until they retire or leave the study.

Some individuals within the study enter the study older than 57. For example, in the year 2000 they are 61 years old, and I start tracking them and then they either fall off or the event happens.

**Desired Output:**

I want to graph the probability on the Y plane and the age on the X plane. What I am trying to convey is that 50% of the population has retired at this age based on the graph.

**Problem:**

The problem however is how do I track them within the study. Do I have a record for each individual for every year in the study until the event happens or they leave the study? Traditionally with this analysis you would start at a time = 0 and then track them, here we are using age as the time window. However here we are tracking individuals who are 57 year or older within the time window 2000-2018. My question is how do I go about recording them to make this analysis work? Or is this the analysis I need to use to get the desired output?

Comment: Welcome to the site, Aslure. I'd like to try to clarify what you are proposing - are you intending to set 'time=0' for each individual at the point where they turn 57, and then your time axis is the number of years since they turned 57? Or are you proposing something different?

Comment: I am proposing something different, is it possible to use age on the X axis and guess the age when the probability is at 50%.

Comment: I don't see why it can't be the same thing? - e.g. using 'day the individual turned 57' as 'time=0', then if the probability is at 50% at 5 years after they turn 57, the age at which the probability is at 50% would be 57+5 = 62 years? If you disagree, can you explain further?

Comment: @Izy The problem with that is some individuals within the study enter the study older than 57 like 62. So in the year 2000 they are 61 years old and I start tracking them and then they either fall off or the event happens. If they all started at 57 this would be so easy.

Comment: I would advise having a careful think about what subjects you can include within your study without introducing bias to the question you are trying to answer. If you only add non-retired people to the study, you will only add people who haven't retired by 61, not the people who have already retired at 61, so your sample would then be biased towards people retiring at a later age.